# Sorting two dimensional array by more than one condition for each column

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a two dimensional array and I want to sort it based on n criterias on different columns. This is an example:

```
ID   Name   GPA   
1    John   3.4
2    John   3.7
3    Aaron  3.0
```

Lets say I want to sort first by name then GPA it should show:

```
ID   Name   GPA
3    Aaron  3.0
2    John   3.7
1    John   3.4
```

I have the following code so far to sort it by one rule only:

```
Arrays.sort(a, new Comparator<String[]>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(String[] entry1, String[] entry2) {
                String time1 = entry1[n]; \\ n is provided column number
                String time2 = entry2[n]; 
                try {
                    double d1 = Double.parseDouble(time1);
                    double d2 = Double.parseDouble(time2);
                    return (int) (d1 - d2);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    return time1.compareTo(time2);
                }

            }
        });
```

where a is my two dimensional array.. my question is, how can I sort by more than one rule? and the number of rules isnt constant as the user would provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right lines with your `Comparator<String[]>`.

You can compose `Comparator`s with `.thenComparing()`, so you could do:

```
Comparator<String[]> byName = Comparator.comparing( row -> row[1] );
Comparator<String[]> byGPA = Comparator.comparing( row -> Double.parseDouble(row[2]) );

Arrays.sort(a, byName.thenComparing(byGPA));
```

Actually you can do this more compactly with:

```
Arrays.sort(a, Comparator.comparing( row -> row[1] )
                         .thenComparing( row -> Double.parseDouble(row[2])));
```

Working with user input, composition like this is ideal - compose at runtime based on what the user inputs.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I sort by more than one rule? and the number of rules isnt constant as the user would provide it

Provide a `Comparator` for each column.

Then you can use the [Group Comparator](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/17/group-comparator/) to combine 2 or more `Comparators` into a single `Comparator` so you can mix and match however you desire.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier for you if you consider a list of objects instead of a two dimentional array.

Then you can make your object [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

```
public class Person implements Comparable {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String gpa;
    ...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person p) {
        // TODO Define how to compare two person
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I thought of this first but I forgot to mention that the columns could be different for each table.. lets say table one has id, name, and gpa but table two might have id, name, age, and gender and I want to make a method to take data, make the array, and print it then loops again to create/sort then next one.

Comment: A class representing a row is still probably better -- you can then do `Comparator.comparing(Row::getName)` instead of `Comparator.comparing( row -> row[1])` for example.

Comment: *"I want to make a method to take data"* : What is this data ?